# One line "x = for... if y not in x"

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to make the `for... if` in the following code into one line:

```
cities = ["Berlin", "Berlin", "Berlin", "London"]

unique_cities = []

for city in cities:
    if city not in unique_cities:
        unique_cities.append(c)

print unique_cities
```

I imagine something like this:

```
unique_cities = [city for city in cities if city not in unique_cities]
```

which of course doesn't work because `unique_cities` is not defined in that loop.

How would I make a one-liner out of this?

Comment: what is `s_cities` ?

Comment: I duped this of the recipe that preserves order; if order doesn't need to be preserved, just use `set()`.

Comment: Nominating to re-open, I think Juicy generally asks about how to write a Python construction more briefly, and only gives `unique` as an example problem that could use that.

Comment: @Kos: you cannot generalise writing one-liners, no. And that would be **way** too broad a question if true.

Comment: Hm... Okay, I'm convinced (also on the ground that this looks a bit like an XY question).

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important, the easier way to accomplish this is just

```
unique_cities = list(set(cities))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to turn it into a set:

```
unique_cities = set(cities)
```